# Is the automorphism group of an $R$-module always a group scheme?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups, group-schemes

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with identity and $M$ an $R$-module.

A group scheme over $R$ is a group object in $\mathrm{Sch}/R$,
or equivalently, a group valued functor $G : \mathrm{Sch}/R \to \mathrm{Grp}$ such that $U \circ G = \mathrm{Hom}_{\mathrm{Sch}/R}(-, G)$, where $U : \mathrm{Grp} \to \mathrm{Set}$ is the forgetful functor.

Is $\mathrm{Aut}_{R}(M)$ then necessarily a group scheme?

I.e. is the functor $R$-algebras $\to \mathrm{Set}$,
$S \mapsto \mathrm{Aut}(M_S) = \mathrm{Aut}(M \otimes_R S)$
representable by some scheme $S \in \mathrm{Sch}/R$?

This is certainly true when $R=k$ is a field and $M = V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over $k$ (in this case, we obtain the algebraic group $\mathrm{GL}_n$), or more generally (I believe) for any $R$, when $M$ is a free module of finite rank.

I believe the answer is 'no' for infinite-dimensional vector spaces or non-finitely generated modules, but I have non idea how to approach such a problem.

Comment: Indeed, It is not a scheme when $M$ is an infinite-dimensional vector space over a field $R$. I suggest that you first look at the functor mapping $S$ to $End(M \otimes_R S)$ (or even just $M \otimes_R S$...), this is a bit easier to understand. And first prove that it is not representable by an affine scheme (just to get started). Remember that representable functors are continuous.

Comment: And when $R$ is not a field, choose a proper nonzero ideal $I$ and define $M = R/I$. Look at the functor here. It won't be representable (except for some degenerate cases).

Comment: You can use the fact that every scheme $X$ is a Zariski sheaf. So any family of compatible points in $X(S_{f_i})$ glue to a unique point in $X(S)$ when $S = (f_i)$.

Comment: Dear @MartinBrandenburg, thank you for the hints! I will try to follow them to produce a proof. I will return here once (if) I managed to work out the details.

Comment: Did you finish the proof?